# Why haven't national elections in some countries devolved into a two-party system despite having an FPTP voting system?

Tags: election, voting-systems

If the First Past the Post voting system is the main culprit behind the formation of two-party systems, why haven't we seen such an outcome in many nations like the U.K and Canada that still use FPTP?

Yes, there are still two dominant parties in these countries, but their parliaments are still much more diverse than the U.S Congress, for example. Why is that?

Comment: The simple version is that the UK and Canada are *regionally* two-party systems.